# Jquery getJson only works after refresh in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, getjson

I've made a script: http://www.carkit-shop.nl/iso2car-stekkers/, as you can see on top of the page there is a selection for cars. These data is being taken from another server.

In all browsers everything works, except for Internet Explorer 8, then the first time you load the page nothing works. And after 1 refresh everything works just as good as all the other browsers?

Does anybody know here why it would only work after one refresh?

Comment: Have you tried to downscale the page to reproduce the problem first? Then debug from there or post question with the downscale code? I hope you don't expect someone to debug for you from the entire page of code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like IE cache gets the result in the first time you call the $.getJSON function but it save the variables in cache and stop calling after this.

To fix the problem, you need to set up the cache property in ajaxSetup to false. Try this:

`$.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false});`

Reference: 
http://www.thushanfernando.com/index.php/2009/10/27/quickfix-jquery-getjson-fails-in-ie6-ie7/

Comment: Muchas gracias hermosa !! funcionó ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just tested with Chrome and IE8. Both look fine.
Please check, wether you have the IE7 compatibility mode switched on.

Btw: please post samples as jsfiddle and not to your companies page

Comment: IE7 has the same problem as IE8 here, it needs to get working in IE7 as well. But the select doesn't contain any loaded results from the external script the first time before the refresh.
I'll make a fiddle, excuse me.